Adding Mexico Permanent Resident status to Trusted Traveler Profile
I need to renew my SENTRI card, so was following the renewal steps in my TTP profile.  One of the questions it asked was about information that had changed - I am now a permanent resident of Mexico, so I checked that option.

Now when going through the rest of the application it said I needed to add proof of status documents showing my permanent resident status, however in here it requires me to put my PR expiry date, and there is no expiry for Mexican permanent residency.


What am I supposed to do here?  The fact that it mentions an "A Number" makes me think they're expecting a US resident card, rather than Mexican, but it was specifically Mexico Permanent Residency that I selected earlier in the renewal application.
It would not let me continue the renewal application without adding my residency details.

I contacted CBP TTP support and asked them what to do, and their response was that I needed a residency card with a MRZ and that if my card didn't have a MRZ then I'd need a new card.  I'm not sure how that solves my issue though, since my card has a MRZ and still I don't have an expiry date to enter.
I have asked them whether I should just make up an expiry date as suggested in comments, or if I should just not select the "Permanent Resident of Mexico" option which then doesn't require my residency details.

Did you contact their tech support by phone or email? https://www.tsa.gov/travel/frequently-asked-questions/i-am-having-trouble-my-global-entrynexussentri-membership-whom#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20questions%20or,227%2D5511%20or%20by%20email.

@NateEldredge yes, but haven't heard anything yet. Hopefully I do...

Since the card doesn't expire, try a future date such as 10/11/3020 and see what happens.

@NateEldredge I received a response from CBP, which was not at all helpful - see the edit to my question

@MarkJohnson I have asked CBP whether that's acceptable...

MRZ has a field for expiration date. What does your card's MRZ have in line 2, positions 22–27?

@NateEldredge <<<<<<

Thus the MRZ field for expiry is empty.

@MarkJohnson - Yes, hence the question.  SENTRI renewal is asking for my Mexico permanent residency expiry, and there isn't one (which is normal for Mexico PR)

Most bigger organisations employ outside firms to devlop their internet applications. This, I think, is one combination that wasn't forseen (that some cards do not expire). Thus my suggestion to try the 100 year solution. If it doesn't work, then you must call the CBP TTP support and ask how fill the field where no expriation date exists (and hope they know that for Mexico this is the general case). Mention also that the MRZ field is empty.
